# Problem with lubuntu 17.04 upgrade

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04

Was prompted to upgrade my lubuntu 16.10 to 17.04. 
After install completes boot process runs to a flashing underscore on screen.

Running on VirtualBox 5.1.12

Pressing 'CTRL-ALT-F2' gets me to a terminal where I can login.

Any ideas?

(I know, I should have backed up vdi file)

Addendum (after Marcelo's answer).

Ran command:

```
dmesg | grep -i "error\|warn\|fail"

Output:
[    0.190337] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling ASPM
[    0.190339] acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
[    1.209761] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at /build/linux-CQR1pk/linux-4.10.0/arch/x86/mm/dump_pagetables.c:226 note_page_0x6a1/0x880
[    1.209772]  --warn+0xea/0x110
[    1.209775]  warn_slowpath_fmt+0x46/0x60
[    1.209846] x86/mm: Checked W+X mappings: FAILED, 96 W+X pages found.
[   10.650235] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

(whew)

Also noticed that when starting the machine that screen attemts to change res a few times before settling at flashing cursor. Note that before upgrade the screen res was 1600*1200 on an old 21"4*3 monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first step can be the analysis of your syslog:

```
dmesg | grep -i "error\|warn\|fail"
```

Perhaps that will give you some clue and will turn your problem more specific.

You can then share the results here.

Answer 2:

As far as I know, you can ignore the "ACPI/disable ASPM" errors.

Have you tried using the recovery mode? During boot, hold SHIFT until the GRUB menu appears, then select the recovery mode option (more than one can be available if you have many kernels installed).

Also, there is a big post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) about many ways one can try and fix boot problems.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, see my addendum to question. Output was a greek to me I'm afraid, I'm an embedded application dev porting code to Linux from a bare-bones system. Not really an OS bod. Sorry for taking so long to see and respond to your answer (diff time zones).